# Recommended strategy for fetching data asynchornously

Tags: multithreading, entity-framework

Lets say that I need to executed several different queries to database. Each query returns different data. Each query will be executed on a thread different than UI thread.

Should I have one thread for all queries to database, or I can freely have one thread per query? What is the recommended practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single `ObjectContext/DbContext` instance should **not** be used for **concurrent** database access because it is not designed for such scenario.

Interacting with objects loaded by different context instances is error prone because all related entity instances should belong to a single context instance. Otherwise you have to attach and detach entities.

If all the operations are reads, then having multiple threads to retrieve data is preferred while for CRUD operations single context instance with a thread is advisable.

Comment: Hi Eranga. Common scenario is that we need to load set of items that are meant for CRUD, and 1 or more set of items that are meant for read-only access (ex reference for CRUD set). Currently what we do is create new thread, and on this thread we fetch all data in sequence (using coroutines). This means that data is retrieved in asynchronous manner, but we do not have parallel queries. Do you find this approach OK, or if not, can you recommend another one?

Comment: @Goran That approach is OK as long as queries are sequential.